# How to compare two IIS 6 configurations

Tags: iis, iis-6, configuration, synchronization

When I have two different machines with IIS 6, let's say for testing and production: Is there a way to compare all settings (App-Pools, Web Service Extensions, ...)?

Or even better: automatically sync both (except IP's etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Start with WebDeploy http://www.iis.net/expand/WebDeploy.  That's meant to copy or sync machines.

To do it manually, you can look at the metabase of each machine (c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\metabase.xml) and use any windiff app to compare them.  Note that encrypted data will be different between the machines so you'll need to skim over that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution provided by stack overflow, this help me to solve my prob.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029045/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-compare-two-servers-iis-settings

Answer (score 0):

All versions of IIS store their configuration in a special database called the metabase. The metabase is in some ways similar to the Windows Registry. Unlike the Windows Registry Editor IIS has no built in tools to view, change or track activity in the Metabase. The IIS Metabase Explorer allows you to view the hierarchical structure of the Metabase, edit the hierarchy or data values, copy or move data from one key to another, backup and restore the database and track changes made to the metabase by any application running on your system. The best thing about the IIS Metabase Explorer is that it is FREE.

You can generate comparision by extracting the hierarchical structure of IIS on different machines.

[Download](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2006/12/iis-metabase-explorer-11) http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2006/12/iis-metabase-explorer-11